# $\mathbb {Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{6}) = \mathbb {Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

$$\mathbb {Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{6}) = \mathbb {Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$$

I know this may seem trivial but could someone please explain the logic behind this statement to me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just did, it's unfortunate that I can only pick one. Thank you, everyone, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\subseteq)$ We have that $\sqrt{6} \in \mathbb Q (\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ because $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3} = \sqrt{6}$. As $\sqrt{2}$ clearly is in $\mathbb Q (\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$, then $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{6}) \subseteq \mathbb Q(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$.

$(\supseteq)$ Notice that $\sqrt{3} = \frac{\sqrt{6}}{\sqrt{2}} \in \mathbb Q (\sqrt{2},\sqrt{6})$ similarly as $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb Q (\sqrt{2} ,\sqrt{6})$ we have  that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}) \subseteq \mathbb Q(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{6})$.

Comment: You're most welcome!

Answer (score 3):

$$\sqrt6=\sqrt2\sqrt3\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt2,\,\sqrt3)$$

$$\sqrt3=\frac{\sqrt6}{\sqrt2}\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt2,\,\sqrt6)$$

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{6})$, as the other inclusion is trivial (note that $\sqrt{6} = \sqrt2 \sqrt3 \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$).

To show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{6})$, it suffices to show that $\mathbb{Q}, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}$ are contained in the right field. It is clear that $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{2}$ are contained in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{6})$, and so is $\sqrt{3}$, as $\sqrt{3} = \frac{\sqrt{6}}{\sqrt{2}} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{6})$.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{6}$ belong to $Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$.

$\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{6}/\sqrt{2}$ and you have the other